# Mongodb file allocator takes more time

Tags: windows, mongodb

When mongodb is creating a new file under data directory it takes more time to create :

> Line 376: Thu Jan 15 18:01:49.407 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile >\data\db\test.3, filling with zeroes...
>   Line 476: Thu Jan 15 18:03:55.650 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile >\data\db\test.3, size: 512MB,  took 126.242 secs

Because of that node give below error after that node is not able to connect with mongodb.

> { "error":"{ err: 'connection to [localhost:27017] timed out' }","level":"error","message":"uncaught exception: ","timestamp":"2015-01-15T20:45:03.702Z"}

My understanding is that this error is coming from MongoMQ lib. I am not sure how I can handle it. Any one can help on this issue.

Comment: What kind of system are you on?  It seems surprising that creating a 512 MB file and filling it with zeros would take two minutes??

Comment: In mongodb I am inserting lacks of messages in mongodb using mongoMQ. lets suppose first time 64MB is allocated for test.0 file. once this fiile is ful then its create test.1 file having 128MB and so on.

Answer (score 3):

**Windows Answer**

The most obvious issue which could apply here is if you are using Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008.  An issue ([SERVER-8480](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8480)) with those operating systems, which can be fixed by applying [this hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2731284) means that the data files being allocated by MongoDB must be filled with zeroes.

That is a lengthy process when compared to the normal method. Unfortunately, even with the hotfix installed, with versions 2.6 and 2.4 MongoDB assumes the problem is still there on Windows 7 or Server 2008 and zero fills anyway.  Version 2.8+ fixes the problem by detecting the hotfix specifically and reverting to not zero filling.

To give you an idea of the difference, here is a sample log line from 2.8.0-rc5 (which detects the fix) on Windows 7:

```
2015-01-22T16:56:51.749+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile E:\data\db\280\test.2, size: 2047MB,  took 0.016 secs
```

And here is a sample log line from the same machine doing the same allocation with version 2.6.5:

```
2015-01-22T16:47:33.762+0000 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile E:\data\db\265\test.2, size: 2047MB,  took 112.071 secs
```

That's 112.071 seconds versus 0.016 seconds.  Windows 8/2012 or 2.8+ (once released, and with the hotfix installed of course) seem to be the way to go here if allocation is causing problems for you.

There are also several more general known issues with versions of MongoDB prior to 2.6.4 on Windows, most notably [SERVER-13729](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13729) and [SERVER-13681](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13681) which were addressed with 2.6.4.

The remaining issues are being tracked in [SERVER-12401](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12401) and are dependent on [this hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2981965) from Microsoft to improve flushing of memory mapped files by the OS.  Unfortunately, that hotfix is only available for Windows 8 and 2012, it has not been made available for Windows 7 and 2008.

Hence, make sure you are using 2.6.4+ at a minimum and, if possible Windows 8 or 2012. It may also be helpful compare any performance seen on remote storage with a local disk to determine if that is a contributing factor.

**Linux Answer**

(preserved in case anyone else ends up here when using Linux)

This should only take a few milliseconds, if you are using a supported filesystem.  I suspect you are using something else (`ext3` perhaps?), or perhaps using a very old version of Linux.

The supported filesystems use [`fallocate()`](https://code.google.com/p/linux-ftools/#fallocate) to allocate the data files, which is very quick.  If this is not supported, then the files must be allocated by filling with zeroes, and that will take a very long time.

Even if that is the case, 126 seconds to zero fill a 512MB file is very slow, which indicates the disk is either slow/broken, or oversubscribed/saturated and struggling to keep up.

If you want to evaluate the allocation outside of MongoDB, I've written a small bash script to [pre-allocate data files for MongoDB](https://github.com/comerford/mongodb-scripts/blob/master/pre_alloc.bash) (for testing purposes), which uses the aforementioned [`fallocate()`](https://code.google.com/p/linux-ftools/#fallocate) and completes in milliseconds for multiple gigabytes on my test system.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I am using mongodb on win7 not the linux

Comment: Updated answer to include possible Windows causes

Comment: I tried to install below hotfix on my system having Window 8.1 Platform: x64
Location: (http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Windows%208.1/Windows%20Server%202012%20R2/sp1/Fix500161/9600/free/476936_intl_x64_zip.exe)
But I am not able to install, while installing The popup message is Windows Update Standalone INstaller , The update is not applicable to your computer.
Can you please help on this why update is not applicable .

Comment: You have to have all other required updates installed first, otherwise you get that message.  The hotfix mentions the specific requirements, but you are usually better off just installing all of the updates via Windows Update. I tested this on a fresh Windows 8.1 and it required multiple Windows Update runs and reboots to get to the point that the hotfix was installable.